# How to generate a mesh with quadrilateral elements?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I have the following code that generates a finite element mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]       
order = 2;
mesh = ToElementMesh[
DiscretizeGraphics[
GraphicsComplex[{{0, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]], "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement, 
"MeshOrder" -> order, "NodeReordering" -> True]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

I'm indicating that the element type i want is a quadrilateral type (`"MeshElementType" -> QuadElement`), but it still creates a mesh of triangles. Can i change this?

Related paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cae.21958

[image]

Comment: it would be easy to hand code for such simple geometry.

Comment: @george2079 i need a very fine mesh. For simplicity i have chosen to shown a coarse mesh in this question. It is very dificult to create more than 1000 nodes by hand.

Comment: i did not literally mean by hand, you would use a loop of course. The density doesn't matter, but the exact shape of the boundary does.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the tutorial [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

> QuadElement meshes behave exactly the same as TriangleElement meshes, with the exception that, for linear quad elements, four incidents per element are needed, and, for quadratic elements, eight incidents per element are needed.

here is another possible answer:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

rectangleA = {{0, 4}, {8, 8}};
rectangleB = {{5, 0}, {8, 4}};

pitch = 0.25;

rectAx = 1/pitch (rectangleA[[2, 1]] - rectangleA[[1, 1]]) + 1;
rectAy = 1/pitch (rectangleA[[2, 2]] - rectangleA[[1, 2]]) + 1;
rectBx = 1/pitch (rectangleB[[2, 1]] - rectangleB[[1, 1]]) + 1;
rectBy = 1/pitch (rectangleB[[2, 2]] - rectangleB[[1, 2]]) + 1;

coordinatesA = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, rectangleA[[1, 1]], rectangleA[[2, 1]], pitch},
   {y, rectangleA[[1, 2]], rectangleA[[2, 2]], pitch}], 1];
coordinatesB = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, rectangleB[[1, 1]], rectangleB[[2, 1]], pitch},
   {y, rectangleB[[1, 2]], rectangleB[[2, 2]], pitch}], 1];

coordinates = Join[coordinatesA, coordinatesB];

incidents = Join[
   Flatten[
    Table[{j*rectAy + i, j*rectAy + i + 1, (j - 1)*rectAy + i + 1, (j - 1)*rectAy + i},
     {i, 1, rectAy - 1}, 
     {j, 1, rectAx - 1}], 1],
   Flatten[
    Table[{j*rectBy + i, j*rectBy + i + 1, (j - 1)*rectBy + i + 1, (j - 1)*rectBy + i},
     {i, 1 + Length[coordinatesA], Length[coordinatesA] + rectBy - 1},
     {j, 1, rectBx - 1}], 1]
   ];

mesh1 = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents]}, 
   "NodeReordering" -> True];
mesh2 = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh1, 2];
mesh2["MeshOrder"]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 DiscretizeGraphics[
  GraphicsComplex[{{0, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
   Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]],
 mesh2["Wireframe"],
 ListPlot[coordinates]
 ]
```

Sample Problem:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100, y == 4 && x <= 5 || y <= 4 && x == 5],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 8 || x == 8]},
  u, {x, y} ∈ mesh2]

sol["ElementMesh"]
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh2, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Here is a different approach. The idea is to first generate a second order triangle mesh. Next a center coordinate is added in every triangle. Then we split every triangle into three first order quads making use of the newly added center coordinate and the initial second order triangle incidents.

[image]

So we add a node in the center of the element and create the quad elements {c,6,1,4}, {c,4,2,5} and {c,5,3,6}.

Start with an initial triangle mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
m = ToElementMesh[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    GraphicsComplex[{{0, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
     Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]]];
```

Two helper functions that work for second order triangle mesh elements. If one want to extend this to 3D then you'd need to add a tetToHex function.

```
getMidEleCoords = Compile[{{eleCoords, _Real, 2}},
   Mean[eleCoords], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

triToQuad = Compile[{{triInci, _Integer, 1}, {midInci, _Integer, 0}}, {
    {midInci, triInci[[6]], triInci[[1]], triInci[[4]]},
    {midInci, triInci[[4]], triInci[[2]], triInci[[5]]},
    {midInci, triInci[[5]], triInci[[3]], triInci[[6]]}
    }
   , RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];

getConverterCode[TriangleElement] := triToQuad;
getNumOfResEle[TriangleElement] := 3
getConvertedEleType[TriangleElement] := QuadElement
```

First, we compute the new coords within the triangle/tet elements:

```
coords = m["Coordinates"];
numOfCoords = Length[coords];
meshEle = m["MeshElements"];
inci = ElementIncidents[meshEle];
markers = ElementMarkers[meshEle];
eleCoords = GetElementCoordinates[coords, #] & /@ inci;
midEleCoords = getMidEleCoords[eleCoords];
numOfMidCoords = Length /@ midEleCoords;
temp = Join[{numOfCoords}, numOfMidCoords];
temp = FoldList[Plus, temp] + 1;
midEleInci = MapThread[Range, {Most[temp], Rest[temp - 1]}];
newCoords = Join[coords, Join @@ midEleCoords];
(*Max[midEleInci]===Length[newCoords]*)
```

The we generate the new elements:

```
newEle = Table[
   Block[{thisMeshEle, thisType, thisInci, thisMarker, converter, 
     newEle, newEleMarkers},
    thisMeshEle = meshEle[[i]];
    thisType = Head[thisMeshEle];
    thisInci = ElementIncidents[thisMeshEle];
    thisMarker = ElementMarkers[thisMeshEle];
    converter = getConverterCode[thisType];
    newEle = Join @@ converter[thisInci, midEleInci[[i]]];
    newEleMarkers = 
     Join @@ Transpose[
       ConstantArray[thisMarker, getNumOfResEle[thisType]]];
    getConvertedEleType[thisType][newEle, newEleMarkers]
    ]
   , {i, Length[meshEle]}];
```

Generate a quad mesh:

```
mq1 = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newCoords, 
  "MeshElements" -> newEle]
(* ElementMesh[{{0., 8.}, {0., 8.}}, {QuadElement["<" 1338 ">"]}] *)
```

Look at the mesh:

```
mq1["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

This is now a first order mesh:

```
mq1["MeshOrder"]
1
```

One can use `MeshOrderAlteration[mq1, 2]` to then subsequently generate a second order mesh.

```
Histogram[Join @@ mq1["Quality"]]
```

[image]

Quality looks OK, but a smoothing of some kind (e.g. Laplacian smoothing) might be well worth trying out.

(*Update:* There is a [follow up question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156611/18437) that discusses the idea of Laplacian smoothing. Spoiler: Does not look like it's worth the trouble)

Solve a model problem over the mesh:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mq1];
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] sol["ElementMesh"]]
```

[image]

Since this will generate three quad elements for every triangle the mesh cell measure is lower than what it needs to be, one could adjust for that by making use of "MaxCellMeasure" in the initial triangle mesh.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

That's not possible in general in V11.0. The only primitive from which a quad mesh can be generated is

```
ToElementMesh[Rectangle[]]
```

or

```
ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

So to get a quad mesh for a more complicated shape you'd need to program a bit and use

```
ToElementMesh["Coordinates"->..., "MeshElements"->{QuadElement[....]}]
```

As another approach you could merge 2 triangles to a quad and thus get a mostly quad mesh. If you do that. I'd be interested in seeing the result.

Here is another piece of information: If you have a first order mesh you can make that second order.

```
m = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents]}];
m["MeshOrder"]
1

m2 = MeshOrderAlteration[m, 2];
m2["MeshOrder"]
2
```

Since your case does not involve curved boundaries no mid side nodes (second order nodes) need to be moved to the proper position.

Comment: don't even try merging triangles, you will end up with horribly unacceptable shape elements.

Comment: @george2079, probably not easy, but it [has been done](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~csverma/CS899_09/qmorph.pdf)

Comment: Are quad elements constrained to single order?

Comment: @Young, no. They can be quadratic.

Comment: I can seem to get `NDSolve` to give an answer higher than single order

Comment: @Young, see update on getting a second order mesh.

Answer (score 16):

this is a bit of a hack but it works for this example:

generate separate rectangle meshes -- note the connected edge nodes must be exactly coincident.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
m1 = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-10, 0}, {0, 10}], 
   "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement, MaxCellMeasure -> 4, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
m2 = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-20, 10}, {0, 30}], 
   "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement, MaxCellMeasure -> 4, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
Show[{m1["Wireframe"] /. EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]] -> EdgeForm[Red], 
  m2["Wireframe"]}]
```

all of this works fine for `"MeshOrder"->2` btw

[image]

join the node lists and shift the second mesh to the new list index:

```
allnodes = Join[m1["Coordinates"], m2["Coordinates"]];
common = Intersection[m1["Coordinates"], m2["Coordinates"]];
m2el = Map[Length@m1["Coordinates"] + # &, m2["MeshElements"] , {2}];
```

now point the duplicate nodes in the second mesh to the nodes in the first mesh:

```
m2el = m2el /. ((Rule @@ Reverse@Flatten[Position[allnodes, #]]) & /@ 
     common);
```

**Edit: This step is not needed for `NDSolve`** `NDsolve` evidently merges coincident nodes (beware other solvers might not do that).

create a new mesh:

```
allelements = Join[m1["MeshElements"], m2el];
ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> allnodes, 
  "MeshElements" -> allelements];
Show[%["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

Note we left stray unconnected nodes in the `allnodes` list, I don't think that should be a problem ..

Edit: test problem: ( with `MaxCellMeasure -> 1/4` )

```
eqns = {
   Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 30], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0]};
uif = NDSolveValue[eqns, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
Graphics[MapThread[{ColorData["SunsetColors"][#2], PointSize[.02], 
    Point[#1]} &,
  {uif["Grid"], uif["ValuesOnGrid"]}]]
```

[image]

a better way to plot..

```
vertvals = ColorData["SunsetColors"]@Extract[uif["ValuesOnGrid"], 
       First@Position[   uif["Grid"] , #] ] & /@ allnodes; 
(* note the "Grid" list and `allnodes` are not the same because of the unused nodes in `allnodes` *)
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[ allnodes,
  Cases[ allelements , {n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_,___} :> 
    Polygon[{n1, n2, n3, n4}], Infinity], VertexColors -> vertvals ]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

**Edit:**

This method is now implemented as `StructuredMesh` function (2D and 3D) in [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) package. With minor enhancements it is also implemented in [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package.

---

If the shape of geometric region can be somehow described as a rectangular array of points then structured quadrilateral mesh can be generated on it. I hope the next example will more clearly illustrate my point.

First we create a raster of 2D points and then pass it to `structuredMesh` function which uses 2D interpolation of each coordinate. It returns `ElementMesh` object according to specified number of elements in each direction.

```
 raster = With[{end = 4 Pi, n = 20},
   N@{
     Table[{x, Sin[x] - 2}, {x, 0, end, end/n}],
     Table[{x, Sin[x]/4}, {x, 0, end, end/n}],
     Table[{x, Cos[x] + 2}, {x, 0, end, end/n}]
     }
   ];

mesh = structuredMesh[raster, {50, 10}, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[Flatten[raster, 1]]}]
 ]
```

[image: mesh_1]

Definition of `structuredMesh` and helper function(s) is given below.

```
getElementConnectivity[nx_,ny_]:=Flatten[
    Table[
        {(i-1)*(nx+1)+j,i*(nx+1)+j,i*(nx+1)+j+1,(i-1)*(nx+1)+j+1},
        {i,1,ny},
        {j,1,nx}
    ],
    1
]


structuredMesh::array="Raster of input points must be full array of numbers with depth of 3.";

structuredMesh//Options={InterpolationOrder->1};
structuredMesh[raster_,{nx_,ny_},opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[
    {order,dim,restructured,xInt,yInt,zInt,nodes,connectivity},
    If[Not@ArrayQ[raster,3,NumericQ],Message[structuredMesh::array];Return[$Failed]];

    order=OptionValue[InterpolationOrder]/.Automatic->1;
    dim=Last@Dimensions[raster];

    restructured=Transpose[raster,{2,3,1}];
    xInt=ListInterpolation[restructured[[1]],{{0,1},{0,1}},InterpolationOrder->order];
    yInt=ListInterpolation[restructured[[2]],{{0,1},{0,1}},InterpolationOrder->order];

    nodes=Flatten[#,1]&@If[dim==3,
        zInt=ListInterpolation[restructured[[3]],{{0,1},{0,1}},InterpolationOrder->order];
        Table[{xInt[i,j],yInt[i,j],zInt[i,j]},{i,0,1,1./ny},{j,0,1,1./nx}]
        ,
        Table[{xInt[i,j],yInt[i,j]},{i,0,1,1./ny},{j,0,1,1./nx}]
    ];

    connectivity=Reverse/@getElementConnectivity[nx,ny];

    If[dim==3,
        ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates"->nodes,"BoundaryElements"->{QuadElement[connectivity]}],
        ToElementMesh["Coordinates"->nodes,"MeshElements"->{QuadElement[connectivity]}]
    ]
]
```

And this is how the function can be used for OP's shape. In general the more complicated shapes can be manually split to "topological quadrialterals", meshed separately with structured meshes and then merged in one mesh.

```
raster2 = {{{5, 0}, {8, 0}}, {{5, 4}, {8, 8}}, {{0, 4}, {0, 8}}};
mesh = structuredMesh[raster2, 10*{1, 2}];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh_2]

Comment: This is a very cool way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:**

This method is now also implemented as `ToQuadMesh` function in [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) package and as `TriangleToQuadMesh` in [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package.

---

Once the open source package is downloaded and installed generating a quad element mesh then works like this:

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
triMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    GraphicsComplex[{{0, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
     Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]]]];

mesh = ToQuadMesh[triMesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: quad mesh]

Note that this also returns a second order mesh:

```
mesh["MeshOrder"]
2
```

---

[AceFEM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/acegen/info) package contains a useful function `SMTTriangularToQuad` which converts triangular mesh to quadrilaterals. It works only for 1st order mesh.

```
<< AceFEM`
triMesh = ToElementMesh[
  DiscretizeGraphics[
    GraphicsComplex[{{0,4},{5,4},{5,0},{8,0},{8,8},{0,8}},Polygon[{1,2,3,4,5,6}]]], 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1
]

mesh = SMTTriangularToQuad[triMesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: quad mesh]

Comment: `ToQuadMesh` is probably the most general method of the solutions presented for this question.

Answer (score 9):

For integer valued coordinates like you have here, you can make a grid of rational step size and use [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) + [`ArrayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayMesh.html).

Something like:

```
mr = MeshRegion[{{0, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 8}, {0, 8}}, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]];

{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = bds = RegionBounds[mr];

δ = 1/10;
xrng = Range[x1, x2 - δ, δ];

onoff = Boole[Table[
  RegionMember[mr, Thread[{xrng, y}]],
  {y, y1, y2 - δ, δ}
]];

quad = ArrayMesh[onoff, DataRange -> bds, DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

```
MeshCellCount[quad]
```

> ```
> {4561, 8960, 4400}
> ```