# Refine a quadrilateral mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have created the following mesh for a slope stability problem:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
    coordinates = {{0., 0.}, {75, 0}, {75, 30}, {45, 30}, {35, 40}, {0, 
        40}, {14, 14}, {60, 14}, {26, 26}, {47, 26}, {28, 28}, {45, 
        28}, {30, 30}, {47, 30}, {60, 30}, {14, 40}, {26, 40}, {28, 
        40}, {30, 40}};
    e1 = QuadElement[{{1, 2, 8, 7}, {2, 3, 15, 8}, {7, 8, 10, 9}, {8, 15, 
         14, 10}, {10, 14, 4, 12}, {9, 10, 12, 11}, {11, 12, 4, 13}, {13, 
         4, 5, 19}, {11, 13, 19, 18}, {9, 11, 18, 17}, {7, 9, 17, 16}, {1,
          7, 16, 6}}];
    mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
      "MeshElements" -> {e1}, "MeshOrder" -> 2, MaxCellMeasure -> 1]
    mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

I'm specifing that the `MaxCellMeasure` shouldn't be larger than one, but mma refuses to refine the mesh. Is there a way to refine this mesh?

This is what I need (mesh generated by GID):

[image]

I have also tried to create a `Region`:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
top = {{1, 2, 8, 7}, {2, 3, 15, 8}, {7, 8, 10, 9}, {8, 15, 14, 
    10}, {10, 14, 4, 12}, {9, 10, 12, 11}, {11, 12, 4, 13}, {13, 4, 5,
     19}, {11, 13, 19, 18}, {9, 11, 18, 17}, {7, 9, 17, 16}, {1, 7, 
    16, 6}};
node = {{0., 0.}, {75, 0}, {75, 30}, {45, 30}, {35, 40}, {0, 40}, {14,
     14}, {60, 14}, {26, 26}, {47, 26}, {28, 28}, {45, 28}, {30, 
    30}, {47, 30}, {60, 30}, {14, 40}, {26, 40}, {28, 40}, {30, 40}};
reg = RegionUnion[
  Flatten[Table[
    Polygon[Table[{ node[[ top[[i]][[j]] ]][[1]], 
       node[[ top[[i]][[j]] ]][[2]] }, {j, 1, 4}]], {i, 1, 
     Length[top]}]]]
Region[reg]
```

[image]
But the function `ToElementMesh` doesn't work:

```
me = ToElementMesh[reg]
me["Wireframe"]
```

Comment: Try `DiscretizeRegion[Region[reg], MaxCellMeasure -> 1]
`

Comment: This will return a triangular element mesh. I need quadrilaterals...

Comment: @Diogo, when you get this to work, would you be able to share the simulation? I'd be interested to se how it's done.

Comment: @user21 I have shared one of my results. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Diogo, thank you - did you implement the Mohr-Coulomb model in Mathematica?

Comment: @user21, no, I implemented it in C++.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica for mesh generation only.

Comment: @Diogo, I see. Can you recommend a reference for the Mohr-Coulomb model?

Comment: Plasticity computations
using the Mohr—Coulomb
yield criterion
M. A. Crisfield
Transport and Road Research Laboratory,
Crowthorne, Berkshire RG11 6AU, UK
(Received December 1986; revised May 1987)

Comment: @Diogo, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it.But with a bit of programming it's not impossible. We (*install and*) load the FEMAddOns:

```
(*ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]*)
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
```

This has the function `StructuredMesh`.

```
coordinates = {{0., 0.}, {75, 0}, {75, 30}, {45, 30}, {35, 40}, {0, 
    40}, {14, 14}, {60, 14}, {26, 26}, {47, 26}, {28, 28}, {45, 
    28}, {30, 30}, {47, 30}, {60, 30}, {14, 40}, {26, 40}, {28, 
    40}, {30, 40}};
incidents = {{1, 2, 8, 7}, {2, 3, 15, 8}, {7, 8, 10, 9}, {8, 15, 14, 
    10}, {10, 14, 4, 12}, {9, 10, 12, 11}, {11, 12, 4, 13}, {13, 4, 5,
     19}, {11, 13, 19, 18}, {9, 11, 18, 17}, {7, 9, 17, 16}, {1, 7, 
    16, 6}};

mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents]}, "MeshOrder" -> 2, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 1];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

We use this to scroll through the structure:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[mesh["Wireframe"], 
  Graphics[Polygon[coordinates[[incidents[[n]]]]]]], {n, 1, 
  Length[incidents], 1}]
```

For one component

```
coordinates[[incidents[[8]]]]

(*{{30, 30}, {45, 30}, {35, 40}, {30, 40}}*)
```

We use

```
raster = {{{30, 30}, {45, 30}}, {{30, 40}, {35, 40}}};
tempMesh1 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 5}];
tempMesh1["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

For the next component we use

```
coordinates[[incidents[[#]]]] & /@ {7, 9}
(*{{{28, 28}, {45, 28}, {45, 30}, {30, 30}}, {{28, 28}, {30, 30}, {30, 
   40}, {28, 40}}}*)

raster = {{{45, 28}, {45, 30}}, {{28, 28}, {30, 30}}, {{28, 40}, {30, 
     40}}};
tempMesh2 = StructuredMesh[raster, {5, 10}];
tempMesh2["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Next, we merge these to meshes. This only works if the nodes of the edges are at exactly the same positions.

```
ElementMeshJoin[m1_, m2_] := Module[
  {c1, c2, nc1, newEle, markers, eleTypes},
  c1 = m1["Coordinates"];
  c2 = m2["Coordinates"];
  nc1 = Length[c1];
  
  newEle = m2["MeshElements"];
  eleTypes = Head /@ newEle; 
  If[ElementMarkersQ[newEle], markers = ElementMarkers[newEle],
   markers = Sequence[]
   ]; newEle = 
   MapThread[#1[##2] &, {eleTypes, ElementIncidents[newEle] + nc1, 
     markers}];
  
  emesh = 
   ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[c1, c2], 
    "MeshElements" -> Flatten[{m1["MeshElements"], newEle}]];
  
  emesh
  ]
```

Join the meshes:

```
newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[tempMesh1, tempMesh2];
newMesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Note carefully that the above mesh has hanging nodes but you get the idea.

The idea is then to do this for the remaining parts.

To then get a second order mesh, use

```
finalMesh = MeshOrderAlteration[newMesh, 2];
```

Other alternatives for quad dominant meshes can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137479/how-to-generate-a-mesh-with-quadrilateral-elements)

Comment: Thank you. This works for me!

Comment: Is it possible to set to 8 instead of 4 noded elements?

Comment: @Diogo, use `MeshOrderAlteration`; see update.

Answer (score 3):

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
    ElementMeshJoin[m1_, m2_] := 
     Module[{c1, c2, nc1, newEle, markers, eleTypes}, 
      c1 = m1["Coordinates"];
      c2 = m2["Coordinates"];
      nc1 = Length[c1];
      newEle = m2["MeshElements"];
      eleTypes = Head /@ newEle;
      If[ElementMarkersQ[newEle], markers = ElementMarkers[newEle], 
       markers = Sequence[]]; 
      newEle = MapThread[#1[##2] &, {eleTypes, 
         ElementIncidents[newEle] + nc1, markers}];
      emesh = 
       ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[c1, c2], 
        "MeshElements" -> Flatten[{m1["MeshElements"], newEle}]];
      emesh]
    c = {{0., 0.}, {75, 0}, {75, 30}, {45, 30}, {35, 40}, {0, 40}, {14, 
        14}, {60, 14}, {26, 26}, {47, 26}, {28, 28}, {45, 28}, {30, 
        30}, {47, 30}, {60, 30}, {14, 40}, {26, 40}, {28, 40}, {30, 40}};
    t = {{1, 2, 8, 7}, {2, 3, 15, 8}, {7, 8, 10, 9}, {8, 15, 14, 10}, {10,
         14, 4, 12}, {9, 10, 12, 11}, {11, 12, 4, 13}, {13, 4, 5, 
        19}, {11, 13, 19, 18}, {9, 11, 18, 17}, {7, 9, 17, 16}, {1, 7, 16,
         6}};
    raster = {{c[[2]], c[[8]]}, {c[[1]], c[[7]]}};
    tempMesh1 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[3]], c[[15]]}, {c[[2]], c[[8]]}};
    tempMesh2 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[8]], c[[10]]}, {c[[7]], c[[9]]}};
    tempMesh3 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[15]], c[[14]]}, {c[[8]], c[[10]]}};
    tempMesh4 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[14]], c[[4]]}, {c[[10]], c[[12]]}};
    tempMesh5 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[10]], c[[12]]}, {c[[9]], c[[11]]}};
    tempMesh6 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[12]], c[[4]]}, {c[[11]], c[[13]]}};
    tempMesh7 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[4]], c[[5]]}, {c[[13]], c[[19]]}};
    tempMesh8 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[11]], c[[13]]}, {c[[18]], c[[19]]}};
    tempMesh9 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[9]], c[[11]]}, {c[[17]], c[[18]]}};
    tempMesh10 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[7]], c[[9]]}, {c[[16]], c[[17]]}};
    tempMesh11 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    raster = {{c[[1]], c[[7]]}, {c[[6]], c[[16]]}};
    tempMesh12 = StructuredMesh[raster, {10, 10}];
    
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[tempMesh1, tempMesh2];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh3];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh4];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh5];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh6];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh7];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh8];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh9];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh10];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh11];
    newMesh = ElementMeshJoin[newMesh, tempMesh12];
    
    newMesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

FEM results:

Here are the elastoplastic (Mohr-Coulomb model)  simulation results for the slope stability problem considering only body forces.

Displacement Field (magnitude):

[image]

Elastic strains (magnitude)

[image]